# Parse multiple child tag XML and Assign data to List view in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have XML file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses>
<apartments>
    <name>Piedra del sol</name>
    <address>6050 Montezuma Road San Diego, CA 92115</address>
    <name>The Suites on Paseo</name>
    <address>5595 Lindo Paseo, San Diego, CA 92115</address>
</apartments>
<atms>
    <name>Bank of America ATM</name>
    <address>5131 College Ave San Diego CA 92182</address>
    <name>US Bank ATM</name>
    <address>6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
</atms>
<banks>
    <name>Bank of America</name>
    <address>6801 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
    <name>US Bank</name>
    <address>6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
</banks>
</addresses>
```

previous to this parsing I have GridView activity. Each child tag in XML is a GridView item. 
I want to parse this XML in following way:
When user clicks on any item from GridView, it should parse content of only that tag and assign it to ListView(Ex: if user clikcs on appartments item from Grid View  then it should assign content of apartments tag to the ListView)Can anyone please suggest me away to do this.

Comment: You can use a XmlPullParser.

Comment: and here is a quick and simple tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html

Comment: @Raghunandan : Can you please post sample code for XMLPullParser to parse XML as shown above.

Comment: @Akshay you have bank but end tag is banks

Comment: @Raghunandan: I made changes to my question. Thank you foe letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

A correction

```
<bank>
    <name>Bank of America</name>
    <address>6801 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
    <name>US Bank</name>
    <address>6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
</banks>
```

TO

```
<bank>
    <name>Bank of America</name>
    <address>6801 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
    <name>US Bank</name>
    <address>6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115</address>
</bank>
```

If you want to display it in a list view you need to parse the xml first. Once you parse the tags you can easily display it in a `ListView`. I have only shown parsing of xml.

You can use a `XmlPullParser`. You can find a example of RSS feed parsign @

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {

    private String text;

    public XMLPullParserHandler() {

    }

    public Void parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);
           String tag = null;
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("apartments")) {
                           tag = "apartments"; 
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("atms")) {
                          tag= "atms";
                    }

                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("bank")) {
                          tag ="banks";

                    }


                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                 if  (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                 Log.i("",tag+" name is "+text);

                 } 
                 else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("address")) {
                  Log.i("",tag+" address is "+text);

                 } 

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Log :

```
04-09 00:22:12.226: I/(1693): apartments name is Piedra del sol
04-09 00:22:12.226: I/(1693): apartments address is 6050 Montezuma Road San Diego, CA 92115
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): apartments name is The Suites on Paseo
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): apartments address is 5595 Lindo Paseo, San Diego, CA 92115
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): atms name is Bank of America ATM
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): atms address is 5131 College Ave San Diego CA 92182
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): atms name is US Bank ATM
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): atms address is 6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): banks name is Bank of America
04-09 00:22:12.236: I/(1693): banks address is 6801 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115
04-09 00:22:12.246: I/(1693): banks name is US Bank
04-09 00:22:12.246: I/(1693): banks address is 6155 El Cajon Blvd San Diego CA 92115
```

Comment: I don't want to parse all the tags at once. previous to this parsing I have GridView activity. Each tag in XML is a GridView item. When user clics on any tag, it should parse content of only that tag(Ex: if user clikcs on appartments item from Grid View  then It should assign content of appartments tag to the ListView)

Comment: @Akshay its upto you to parse all tags are only tags that you want. I can show a general example

Comment: @Akshay by the way you haven't mentioned what you need exactly in your question. So if you have a specific problem post a new question with relevant details. GridView has nothing to do with parsing.

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes it's upto me but may I know how can I tell the parser that I want content of specific tag only.

Comment: @Akshay parse all tags but display only those data that you need. So you can use a collections or a class with getter and setter.